# Interfacing with an LCD screen

Tags: spi, lcd, i2c

I have managed to salvage the LCD screen from an old Tom-Tom (the model number of the screen is LTE430WQ-F0B-0BS). It comes with a driver for the screen on the back, but it doesn't look humanly possible to solder/interface with it in any way. However, this driver connects to 4 wires going into the LCD, which look easy to solder. I was wondering whether it'd be possible to skip the driver already there, and simply connect the 4 wires to the GPIO of an Arduino or something similar. I have looked for some time for this solution, but only found data sheets which referenced the on-screen driver.

Answer (score 2):

Those 4 wires do not go to the LCD, but to the touchscreen. It is most likely a 4-wire resistive touchscreen.

Comment: Is there any way to get past the driver?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You would want to interface with the driver. The driver has hundreds of pins that connect directly to the rows/columns of the LCD, so the most feasible way to communicate would be to sever the connection between the TomToms controller and the driver, and try to talk to the driver directly using the Arduino.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point. But, the wires on the driver are extremely small. Do you have any tips on how to connect them to an Arduino?

Comment: It would be really difficult to access the pins. I think this kind of thing falls into the category of not-worth-the-time-to-hack, especially considering you can just get a color LCD shield on eBay for like ~$20. The TomTom screen driver will likely need more than 10 pins because the data is sent parallel for speed reasons, and it will be a nightmare to bring those pins out to the Arduino.

Comment: Yes, that's very true. Looks like I'll just have to buy one. Thanks for your time :)